# Finding the contribution of a voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis, superposition

So i am trying to find the contribution of the voltage source in the circuit shown across the 3 ohms resistor. Do I need to include the two 2 ohm resistors even though there is no path that starts at the 3 Ohms and ends at the negative side while passing through those resistors
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to find the contribution of the 3V source ONLY across the 3ohm resistor? If so this is a superposition question. Open circuit the 2A source. Redraw the circuit and solve. @ThePhoton you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to include the two 2 ohm resistors even though there is no path that starts at the 3 Ohms and ends at the negative side while passing through those resistors

You are correct. The two 2-ohm resistors will not affect the solution for the current through the 3-ohm resistor, and removing them from the circuit will not affect the solution.